# Stored procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I need your help in writing a stored procedure to update the data given below into a table in SQL Server.

I have uploaded a picture to ensure format is set right.

The second column which identifies the part number, example: `part 100` has `103` and `104` as its components in bill of materials. However only 1 (either 103 is allocated to id `1`, `part 100` or `104` is allocated to id `2`, `part 100`).

For us to differentiate during the planning bill of materials for the top level assembly, we need to update assembly hashkey (string) with the last character of component used (ex: `103`, use `3`), `000111` becomes `300111`. Doesn't matter which component gets assigned to the parent.

Can anybody please help me with this. thanks.

```
Data Structure          Expected result

ID  Part  hashkey       ID  Part    hashkey
-----------------       --------------------
1   100   000111        1   100     300111
2   100   000111        2   100     400111
3   103   000111        3   103     000111
4   104   000111        4   104     000111
```

Data structure:
[expected_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB93Q.png)

Comment: Is `hashkey` is `string` data type?

Comment: Part 100 has components 101-109 and part 110 has components 111-119?

Comment: Looks like expected result does not meet this condition: __update assembly hashkey with the last character of component used (ex: 102, use 2), 000111 becomes 200111__

Comment: If expected result is good, you need: `cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.[PART] ORDER BY t.[ID]) as varchar(10))` and to replace first N chars of `hashkey` by obtained value with respect to it's length

Comment: How do you know that ID1 should be updated with a 1 instead of a 2?

Comment: @Praveen, yes, hashkey is a string.

Comment: @TabAlleman, doesn't matter which component gets assigned to the parent assembly. Either one can get assigned. this is a planning bill and used for forecasting model then for actual build. So, if there are 3 parent assembly (same part number, 100), there will be 3 components (103, 104, 105) or could be 2 as in the above example. there will always be even total number of records, 3 parent +3 component. Challenge is to assign the component to each parent without assigning the same component twice to the parent assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I understand your requirement now, then this should do it:

```
WITH cteParent AS (
 SELECT Id, hashkey, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By hashkey, Order by ID) AS rn
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE Part=100
)
, cteComponent AS (
 SELECT Id, hashkey, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By hashkey, Order by ID) AS rn
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE Part<>100
)
SELECT t.Id, t.Part
, CASE
    WHEN t.Part=100 THEN RIGHT(CAST(c.Part AS varchar(31)),1) + SUBSTRING(CAST(p.hashkey AS varchar(31)), 2, LEN(CAST(t.hashkey AS varchar(31)))-1)
    ELSE CAST(t.hashkey AS varchar(31))
  END AS hashkey
FROM MyTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteParent p ON t.Id=p.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteComponent c 
 ON p.hashkey=c.hashkey
 AND p.rn=c.rn
ORDER BY ID asc
```

Comment: worked perfect. Thank you. I was able to make necessary modifications to the SQL with real part numbers and couple other fields to make up the hashkey and do the allocation. Using the row number to assign the component with Parent was smart.  I didn't think of it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (ID INT, Part INT, hashkey VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @data
SELECT 1, 100, '000111'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 100, '000111'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 101, '000111'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 102, '000111';

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ID, Part, hashkey, ROW_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY part ORDER BY part ASC
            ) AS RN
    FROM @data
    )
SELECT ID, Part, CASE 
        WHEN RN > 1
            THEN cast(ID AS VARCHAR) + hashkey
        WHEN lead(RN, 1) OVER (
                ORDER BY part, RN
                ) > 1
            THEN cast(ID AS VARCHAR) + hashkey
        ELSE hashkey
        END AS hashkey
FROM cte
```

Comment: I ran the code and the expected outcome is different then what I was expecting. I updated the image to highlight the different. The last character of the component (doesn't matter which one, 103 or 104 * changed the numbers to make it clear) should be updated in one of the parent assembly hash. In your code, the parent id is used to update the hash instead of component. Added few comments to other posts make it more clear. Thanks.